# modify a stringbuilder while iterating on it

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

In Java, can I iterate on the content of a StringBuilder and delete/insert/replace chars such that the loop will stay consistent? If so, best practice, shall I use for-loop, iterator, or traditional loop from zero to length()-1? E.g.,

```
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder("12345");
for (int i=0; i< b.length(); i++) //traditional loop, iterator(which?),other?
  char c= b.chartAt(i);
  if(c == '1') b.deleteCharAt(i); // reduce the size,what is i pointing to now?
  if(c=='2') b.insert(i,"two"); //increase the size
```

}

Edit: say I have a big string and I need to do changes on it and I dont' want to produce copies every time. StringBuilder is a mutable string, how can I use it properly to do inplace changes? I know I can use replace / replaceall on the String itself, but this is not the point here.

Comment: If you want to delete anything it's better to iterate from the end to start of the String.

Comment: why do you have `b.insert(2,"two")`? it should be `i` or `2`?

Comment: thanks, fixed! it is i of course!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that. I agree with STaefi, you should iterate from the end to start:

```
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder("12345");
        for (int i = b.length() - 1; i >=0 ; i--){ //traditional loop, iterator(which?),other?
            char c = b.charAt(i);
            if(c == '1') b.deleteCharAt(i); // reduce the size,what is i pointing to now?
            if(c=='2') b.insert(2,"two"); //increase the size
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you should change the value of `i` accordingly.

```
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder("12345");
for (int i=0; i< b.length(); i++) {
      char c= b.chartAt(i);
      if(c == '1'){
          b.deleteCharAt(i);
          i--; // because you don't want to miss out the next char after deleting the present char
      }
      else if(c=='2'){
             b.insert(i,"two"); // I am not sure you want 2 or i
             i=i+2; // change this accordingly.
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a `StringBuilder` then you're probably doing something wrong, because it just's designed for the different purpose (e.g. dynamically string buildings as you've noticed from its name). If you want to get a new char-sequence by changing some of them use `String` if you don't have some specific requirements.

Comment: the point is, say I have a big string and I know I have to do a lot of changes. I don't want to create copies all the time, but using a StringBuilder as mutable string, which is what this class is all about.

Comment: If you want mutability, why don't you use StringBuffer instead? Why is the usage of StringBuilder neccesary? I mean it may confuse other developers...

Comment: sorry i don't get that. StringBuffer and StringBuilder are essentially that same, just caring about thread-safe, as far as I know